# Two-look Gaussian channel

Tags: probability, random-variables, information-theory, entropy

I'm reading through a solution from Elements of Information Theory by Thomas A. Cover. This is the two-look Gaussian channel, where the input to the channel is $X$ and the output is $(Y_1, Y_2)$.

$Y_1 = X + Z_1$

$Y_2 = X + Z_2$

where $(Z_1, Z_2) = Normal(0, K)$, where $K = \begin{bmatrix} N & N \rho \\ N \rho & N \end{bmatrix}$

There is a power constraint on $X$ : $Var(X) = P$

Now, I understand that the channel capacity is maximized when the distribution of $X$ is Gaussian - $Normal (0, P)$. And since $(Y_1, Y_2)$ are combinations of $X$ and $(Z_1, Z_2)$, they must also be normally distributed.

The solution says that $(Y_1, Y_2)$ is distributed as $Normal\left( 
0, \begin{bmatrix} N + P & N \rho + P \\ N \rho + P  & N + P \end{bmatrix} \right)$

How is this distribution of $(Y_1, Y_2)$ obtained? Why does $P$ get added to all elements of the covariance matrix?

Comment: So you know $(Y_1,Y_2)$ has a normal distribution. You only need to find it's mean vector and the correlations matrix. But remember that for Gaussian Channel $X$ and $Z$ are assumed not to be correlated. . . So try to compute the variance and correlations by any formula you know, use the correlation 0 to cancel terms...

Comment: Thanks, got it!

Comment: If you've found the answer, please either wrote yourself it as answer and accept it, or delete the question, so it does not appear as waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is known that the Gaussian noises $Z_1, Z_2$ are zero mean. If we try to find the variance of each of the $Y_1, Y_2$ pairs, we could write the elements of the covariance matrix $L$ of the form: 
$$
L_{11} = E[Y_1Y_1] = E[(X+Z_1)(X+Z_1)] = E[X^2] + 2E[XZ_1] + E[Z^2] = P + 0 + N = P+N
$$
$$
L_{12} = E[Y_1Y_2] = E[(X+Z_1)(X+Z_2)] = E[X^2] + E[XZ_1] + E[XZ_2] + E[Z_1Z_2] = P + 0 + 0 + \rho N = P+ \rho N
$$
The other two elements of the covariance matrix can be obtained through symmetry.